# Simple string pattern crashes kernel

Tags: bugs, string-manipulation, crash

**Bug introduced in 6.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.1.0**

---

The following code crashes my Mathematica kernel (v9, MacOS):

```
s = StringJoin[ConstantArray["65 H Isotropic = 27.4022 Anisotropy = 4.3297\n", 400]];
StringCases[s, (Except["\n"]..~~"\n")..];
```

Is this a known problem? Am I using string patterns in a wrong way?

Comment: I can reproduce this in MMA9 och MMA10 on OS X.

Comment: No problem with version 10 on Windows 7

Comment: Even if you are using string patterns incorrectly, you shouldn't get a kernel crash.

Comment: It crashes on Linux v8 as well.

Comment: Can reproduce on v10 Linux x64.

Comment: on OSX and v10, it crashes as well

Comment: Reproduced in all of 8.0.4, 9.0.1 & 10.0.0 on OS X 10.9.4.

Comment: No problem with 10.0.0 on win8.1 x64.

Comment: Fixed as of version 10.1.0.

Answer (score 3):

Is your `StringCases` expression intended to recover the 400 individual strings (without their terminating new-lines) that were joined to form `s`? If so, your pattern should have been

```
ss2 = StringCases[s, Except["\n"] ..];
```

although I suggest

```
ss3 = StringSplit[s, "\n"];
```

would have been a better way to do it.

Nevertheless, as I wrote in a comment to your question, what you evaluated should not have crashed the kernel, because, ideally, the kernel should never crash.

Comment: The expression is a minimum working example derived from a more complicated string pattern used in parsing part of the output of a quantum chemistry program. The original input indeed had a header followed by multiple data lines followed by footer format. I was interested in one number in each line and a fast solution as I have to parse many of these files. Ideally I wanted a single pattern returning these numbers. The problem also seems a matter of input size: If you replace 400 by 100 in my example, evaluation goes through.

Comment: @mrupp. That it is a matter of input size is no surprise. Many kernel crashes are data size dependent.